# Php parse string error

Tags: php, parsing, dom, strpos

I am extracting files from a string which can be entered by a user or taken from reading a page source.

I want to extract all .jpg image URLs

So, I am using the following (example text shown) but a) it only returns the first one and b) it misses off '.jpg'

```
$word1='http://';
$word2='.jpg';

$contents = 'uuuuyyyyyhttp://image.jpgandagainhereitishttp://image2.jpgxxxxcccffff';

$between=substr($contents, strpos($contents, $word1), strpos($contents, $word2) - strpos($contents, $word1));

echo $between;
```

Is there maybe a better way to do this?

In the case of parsing a web page I cannot use a simple DOM e.g. `$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');` as sometimes the image references are not in standard tags

Comment: Of course it'll only return the first one. You don't check the string for further matches. This should be (debatable) done in a loop, progressively moving up the 'start' point to catch later matches.

Comment: Or you could just use regular expressions, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
<?php

$contents = 'uuuuyyyyyhttp://image.jpgandagainhereitishttp://image2.jpgxxxxcccffff';

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('#(http://[^\s]*?\.jpg)#i',$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this using `preg_match_all` (as previously answered) or alternatively use the following function.

It simply explodes the original string, checks all parts for a valid link and adds it to the array, that's getting returned.

```
function getJpgLinks($string) {
    $return = array();
    foreach (explode('.jpg', $string) as $value) {
        $position = strrpos($value, 'http://');
        if ($position !== false) {
            $return[] = substr($value, $position) . '.jpg';
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```